# Why according to python -a(b+c) != a(-b-c)?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I was coding on python (Anaconda) and while working with sympy I noticed this issue:

```
import sympy as sym

a = sym.Symbol('a')

b = sym.Symbol('b')

c = sym.Symbol('c')

-a*(b+c) == a*(-b-c)

Out[190]: False
```

Why is this happening?

[image: Picture of my code]

Comment: See [sympy's gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs): *Double equals signs (`==`) are used to test equality. However, this tests expressions exactly, not symbolically.

Comment: @Johan - that should be an answer, rather than a comment.  (Comments are for improving the question, yes?)

Comment: @TobySpeight Comments with just a link aren't really answers. Often such questions are duplicates. Often they get closed by the mods. By the way, the real answer should include `sym.Eq(-a * (b + c), a * (-b - c)).simplify()` as the way to do this in sympy. The way sympy is integrated into Python has a few "gotchas", including `==` not being symbolic, divisions that get converted into floats instead of into fractions and `^` only meaning `exclusive or`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it may have to do with how Sympy treats the overloads for the `Symbol` object.

Your statement is comparing two *object references*.

It looks like you're just doing math and comparing values, but that's not what's going on under the hood. Look at the [gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's my first time using this sub. it seems that the function sym.simplify should do the trick. Thanks!